# No puedo ver la información de mi base de datos

Tags: php, xampp, mariadb

**EDITO LA PREGUNTA**

Tras unos días probando he visto que mi codigo `php` era correcto, cuando he ejecutado simplemente esa parte de código con un archivo .php ha funcionado a la primera. El problema viene al tenerlo insertado en mi index.html.

Si alguien es tan amable de explicarme el motivo, decirme que hago mal, que me dejo, se lo agradecería. Gracias.

**----------------------------------------------**

**Pregunta vieja**

Buenas, estoy mirando conceptos de SQL y nada más empezar ya tengo mis primeros problemas. Básicamente es que no se me muestra la información.

Desde phpmyadmin cree una base de datos llamada "bd_crsng" y dentro una tabla llamada "datospersonales", esta a su vez contiene los campos nombre, apellido, edad y NIE.

Básicamente lo primero que quiero hacer es mostrar dicho contenido.

Este es mi código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<HTML lang="es">

<HEAD>
  <title> Crsng </title>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

</HEAD>

<BODY>

  <?php
          
           $db_host = "localhost/phpmyadmin/";
           $db_nombre = "bd_crsng";
           $db_usuario = "root";
           $db_contra = "";
           
           $conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre);
           
           $consulta = "SELECT * FROM datospersonales";
           
           $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
           
           $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resultados);
           
           echo $fila[0];
           
       ?>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Yo creo que mi error viene que no estoy llamando bien a la carpeta, o contraseñas, usuarios... Por si sirve de algo uso win10 y el programa es xampp.

Saludos!

Comment: Has probado que la conexión te funciona bien?. Intenta mostrar un error en caso de conexión a la base de datos, para segurarte. Podría ser algo asi $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username,$password, $database);
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
die( "Fallo la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_errno() 
. ") " . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
echo "Conexión exitosa!";
$mysqli -> mysqli_close();

Comment: El **$db_host = "localhost/phpmyadmin/";** debería ser **$db_host = "localhost";** el `/phpmyadmin/` sobra. Igualmente como te comentan los compañero lo adecuado es ir verificando cada paso y comprobar que errores te arroja mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que vayas comprobando que el código se está ejecutando correctamente, ya que puede fallar en muchos sitios por muchas cosas y así te sería más fácil localizar el error. Por ejemplo:

```
if (! ($conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra, $db_nombre);)) {
    // Si entra aqui es que ha fallado la conexion
}
```

También puedes usar

```
mysqli_error($conexion)
```

Para ver si así consigues averiguar un poco mejor qué ocurre.

Answer (score 0):

Siendo cierto lo que te comentan arriba de probar la conexión, intenta algo así

```
$query = "select * from $tabla_db1";     // Esta linea hace la consulta
$result = mysql_query($query); 

while ($registro = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
echo " 
    <tr> 
      <td width='150'>".$registro['id']."</td> 
      <td width='150'>".$registro['nombre']."</td> 
      <td width='150'>".$registro['email']."</td> 
      <td width='150'></td> 

    </tr> 
"; 
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado